# PHP Generate Timestamp with No Special Character

Tags: php, timestamp, special-characters

Trying to generate a timestamp as a string variable with no special characters, including month-day-year-minute-hour-second (in no specific order) for example:

```
$dateProcessed = '10302014133952'
```

Preferred a 24 hour cycle on the hour (like 13 instead of 1pm).

Suggestions?

Comment: Why do you not just use a normal timestamp? The `time()` function will give you that.

Comment: I need to create unique skus, but they arent indefinitely being added to the system, so serialization of using something like a uniqueid wont work because if a product doesnt get added to the system, it will still have had its sku used. Using a timestamp including the date seemed like a good solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty basic:

```
echo date('mdYHis');  // 10302014204259
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/213997)

It's just a string. Use `date()` to output the date string in whatever format you want.